# Using setTimeout to delay d3 transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, settimeout

I am trying to create a simple plane animation along a spiral curve

However, I encountered issue when trying to delay the transition using d3's delay function, the animation does not seem to go correctly

So I have been contemplating using setTimeout to delay the triggering of the transition function, but could not seem to get it right. Could someone give me a suggestion?

[Link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duck0/66u12oxv/14/). This includes the original transition without setTimeout or any .delay; v15 shows the error with using .delay; and v16 has what I have tried with setTimeout

This is my code for transitioning without setTimeout (which works fine without .delay)

```
function transitionThis(d,i) {
d3.select(this).transition()
.duration(3000)
//.delay(3000) //causes error in the animation
.ease("exp")
.each("start", function() { d3.select(this).style("opacity", "1"); })    
  .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
  .styleTween("opacity", function () {return d3.interpolate("1", "0");});}

plane.each(transitionThis);

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
    var t0 = 0;
    return function(i) {
  return function(t) {
    var p0 = path.getPointAtLength(t0 * l);//previous point
    var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);////current point
    var angle = Math.atan2(p.y - p0.y, p.x - p0.x) * 180 / Math.PI;//angle for tangent
    t0 = t;
  return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y +  ")scale(" + (0.2+t*4) + ")rotate(" + angle +"15"+")";
};
  };
}
```

and this is my attempt at adding setTimeout

```
function transitionThis(d,i) {
d3.select(this).transition()
.duration(3000)
//.delay(3000) //causes error in the animation
.ease("exp")
.each("start", function() { d3.select(this).style("opacity", "1"); })    
  .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
  .styleTween("opacity", function () {return d3.interpolate("1", "0");});
}

function delayedFlight() {
var tOut = setTimeout(transitionThis(),3000);
}
plane.each(delayedFlight);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening: for some reason, adding `.delay()` to the transition makes it so that every once in a while the interpolation function (the one that returns the transform value) gets called two times in a row with the same value of `t`. For example, here's a subset of the output I got when I inserted `console.log(t)`:

```
0.006692062648206693
0.006707542472169953
0.007238969233518517
0.007255714140926161
0.0077049430038543705
0.0077049430038543705 // <- same as previous
0.008568945153864268
0.008588766510821856
0.00899496468906235
0.00899496468906235   // <- same as previous
0.009529833123126597
0.00955187716946928
0.01107410052517391
0.011099716711945125
0.012516716837337842
```

I'm not why it happens, but technically it's not a bug, just a quirk. However, it causes a sort of bug with your interpolation function: When `t0` and `t` are equal, so are `p0` and `p` and as a result the computed `angle` is 0 for those intermittent cases. And that's when you see the plane stutter – whenever its rotation is set to 0.

The easiest fix is to make it so that `t0` and `t` are never equal, which can be achieved by intercepting that condition and modifying `t0` a bit. Like this:

```
    // Happens every once in a while
    if (t == t0) {
        // Move t0 "back in time" a bit
        t0 -= .00001;
    }
```

It's not so pretty, but is probably still better than getting into setTimeouts....

[Here's the modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66u12oxv/18/)

Comment: Ah I see, that explains it. It may not be the prettiest fix, as you say, but I agree, a whole lot cleaner than fitting setTimeout in the middle of it. Thanks a lot meetamit!!!

Comment: The bug doesn't occur for small timeouts, so my best guess is that after a large amount of time the browser has taken care of all the (delayed) rendering and loading and therefore the animation frames come quicker. Note that there's nothing in the D3 source to prevent (or even detect) duplicate values for `t`.